# Discrete Math: Propositional Satisfiability

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I've been studying Discrete Mathematics and its Applications, and so far I think its pretty straightforward, however there is an example that I am having trouble understanding.  It involves using propositional logic to create a strategy to solve a sudoku puzzle.  See image below:

[Image of Assertions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEV1w.png)

However, how is one to construct the conjunction of disjunctions?  I've tried the following but dont believe its right

[My representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b38XO.jpg)

TIA

Answer (score 1):

The expression

$$\bigwedge_{i=1}^9\bigwedge_{n=1}^9\bigvee_{j=1}^9p(i,j,n)$$

expands like this:

$$\begin{align*}
&\color{red}{\big(p(1,1,1)\lor p(1,2,1)\lor p(1,3,1)\lor\ldots\lor p(1,9,1)\big)}\\
&\qquad\color{red}{\land\big(p(1,1,2)\lor p(1,2,2)\lor p(1,3,2)\lor\ldots\lor p(1,9,2)\big)}\\
&\qquad\color{red}{\land\big(p(1,1,3)\lor p(1,2,3)\lor p(1,3,3)\lor\ldots\lor p(1,9,3)\big)}\\
&\quad\;\;\;\,\color{red}{\land\;\ldots}\\
&\qquad\color{red}{\land\big(p(1,1,9)\lor p(1,2,9)\lor p(1,3,9)\lor\ldots\lor p(1,9,9)\big)}\\
&\qquad\land\color{blue}{\big(p(2,1,1)\lor p(2,2,1)\lor p(2,3,1)\lor\ldots\lor p(2,9,1)\big)}\\
&\qquad\color{blue}{\land\big(p(2,1,2)\lor p(2,2,2)\lor p(2,3,2)\lor\ldots\lor p(2,9,2)\big)}\\
&\quad\;\;\;\,\color{blue}{\land\;\ldots}\\
&\qquad\color{blue}{\land\big(p(2,1,9)\lor p(2,2,9)\lor p(2,3,9)\lor\ldots\lor p(2,9,9)\big)}\\
&\quad\;\;\;\,\land\;\ldots\\
&\qquad\land\color{green}{\big(p(9,1,1)\lor p(9,2,1)\lor p(9,3,1)\lor\ldots\lor p(9,9,1)\big)}\\
&\qquad\color{green}{\land\big(p(9,1,2)\lor p(9,2,2)\lor p(9,3,2)\lor\ldots\lor p(9,9,2)\big)}\\
&\quad\;\;\;\,\color{green}{\land\;\ldots}\\
&\qquad\color{green}{\land\big(p(9,1,9)\lor p(9,2,9)\lor p(9,3,9)\lor\ldots\lor p(9,9,9)\big)}
\end{align*}$$

Each row is one of the disjunctions $\bigvee\limits_{j=1}^9p(i,j,n)$. The color changes every time that $i$ increases by $1$, so the red rows give you $\bigwedge\limits_{n=1}^9\bigvee_{j=1}^9p(1,j,n)$, with $i=1$; the blue rows give you $\bigwedge\limits_{n=1}^9\bigvee_{j=1}^9p(2,j,n)$, with $i=2$; and so on, until the green rows give you $\bigwedge\limits_{n=1}^9\bigvee_{j=1}^9p(9,j,n)$, with $i=9$.

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot!  I didn't know you could write the math symbols on here, that will definitely help in the future instead of taking pictures lol.  Also, I'm visualizing basically a scan of every cell from left to right and inputting 1 first, then going back and inputting 2 in each cell in each column, etc... and then moving to the next row and using the same process till the end, and once each and every proposition is true, it results in the solution.  Would that be an accurate visualization?

Comment: @ArturoCastillin: (There’s a basic tutorial and reference for writing math on this site [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Yes, if I’m understanding you correctly. If you’re familiar with nested summation notation, this works the same way: like nested loops in computer programming. You’re welcome!